# Avoid browser crash by reloading a web page (high memory usage)

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache, x3dom

I have the following problem. I developed a web page (or a web gallery) using JavaScript and X3DOM. By reloading the web page, the memory usage rise up to 3GB and the firefox browser crashes. By forcing the hard refresh using CTRL + F5 the browser doesn't crash. Now I'm looking for a solution. I think there is no possibility to force the hard refresh by every page reload initiated by user. The "no cache" meta tag in the HTML document didn't help me. I hope someone can give me some propositions to solve this problem.

Here is the affected web page URL: http://putrajaya.victoriasoft.de/gallery/gallery.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to minimize the elements in the DOM by putting all your elements in one inline.x3d. And group them there. This helped us a lot. Because Firefox needs Furthermore the X3DOM guy are already aware of a bug which might be related to that: https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/issues/227 (it might help if you push it also a bit).

Comment: @mistapink Thank you for your proposition and link. If I will find some time to restructuring, I gonna try it out.